# Only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC error

Tags: php, laravel

I've copied laravel on a shared host and after configuring I'm getting `The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths` error and i don't have any idea what i did wrong and after searching on stackoverflow in all of answers they recommended to run a command but i don't have access to ssh. how can i fix it?

Comment: You need to run the command 'php artisan key:generate' in order to fix this issue. If you don't have access to SSH you will not be able to fix this issue. So get SSH access or ask someone else to execute the command for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fix this without having SSH access.

This error usually occurs when `APP_KEY` is not set in the `.env` file or the `.env` is missing entirely.
If you just cloned your repository, the `.env` is usually missing because it's listed in the .gitignore (by default).

If you copied the default `.env.example`, you'll notice the `APP_KEY` is left blank.

Just ensure the `.env` file is present and use `php artisan key:generate` and you'll get a new random and valid key.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, looks like it works.

Need to create key file in .env file so run it `php artisan key:generate`. I then copied the output in the brackets, and put in my .env file as `APP_KEY=base64:keygoesherenotpostingmyrealkey`. I did `php artisan config:clear`, then `php artisan config:cache`, and things are now working!